# Import * include submodules

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
scripts/
    __init__.py
    filepaths.py
    Run.py
    domains/
        __init__.py
        topspin.py
        tiles.py
        hanoi.py
        grid.py
```

I would like to say:

```
from scripts import *
```

and get the stuff that is in filepaths.py but also get the things that are in hanoi.py

The outer `__init__.py` contains:

```
__all__ = ['filepaths','Run','domains','hanoi']
```

I can't figure out how to get the inner files to be included in that list.  Putting hanoi by itself gets this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'hanoi'
```

Putting domains.hanoi gets this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'domains.hanoi'
```

The last reasonable guess I could come up with is putting scripts.domains.hanoi which gets this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scripts.domains.hanoi'
```

How do you get the all list to include things that are in subdirectories?

Comment: I guess, “don't use * imports” is not what you want to hear, but still…

Comment: You can't do _exactly_ what you want, and that's at least partly because (as @kirelagin says) you shouldn't want to do it. If you can explain what you really care about here, maybe we can explain a better way to accomplish it than making `from pkg import *` work recursively without modifying the packages (which is what you're asking for).

Comment: I would like to use one import statement that will allow me to say hanoi.foo() and tiles.foo().  The way things are structured now I have to say something like scripts.domains.hanoi.foo() which is way too long, or move everything into one directory, which would get crowded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `scripts/__init__.py`, before the `__all__` add the following

```
from domains import topspin, tiles, hanoi, grid
```

This will add those modules to the namespace, and you will be able to import them with

```
from scripts import *
```

**Note**

As a soapbox, it is preferred to do things like

```
from scripts import topspin, tiles, hanoi, grid, filepaths, Run
```

over

```
from scripts import *
```

because 6 months from now, you might look at `hanoi` on the 400th line of code and wonder where it came from if you use the `*` import style.  By explicitly showing what is imported from `scripts` it serves as a reminder where things come from.  I'm sure that anyone trying to read your code in the future will thank you.

Comment: from domains import topspin, tiles, hanoi, grid
    __all__ = ['filepaths','Run','topspin', 'tiles', 'hanoi', 'grid']

The list needed commas, if you fix that I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks.  It was a copy paste and I forgot to add the commas.

Comment: If you use python interactively import * is your friend.  I agree if you're building a program it can cause problems, but like I said, if you're doing something small interactively you definitely come to appreciate the *.

Comment: True.  I wasn't thinking in terms of interactive use, but you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Import them first, in the `__init__` files.

In `scripts/__init__.py`, import at least `domains`, and in `scripts/domains/__init__.py` import `hanoi`, etc. Or import `domains.hanoi` directly in `scripts/__init__.py`.

Without importing these, the `scripts/__init__.py` module has no reference to the nestend packages.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, how should the init.py files change?