# How to expand os.path to include submodules

Tags: python, pyqt4

I made a simple code editor using PyQt4.

Problem is when opening and executing a file that depends on a sub module,
it cant find it locate them even when in same folder.

I try to expand `os.path`, in editor so it behaves like running a script strait from windows.

the other solutions I read here an stackoverflow.
is only solutions if you would know what all the sub modules are called.

[Import * include submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972216/import-include-submodules)

[How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python?rq=1)

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), os.path.expandvars('%Path%'))


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
    Form.resize(845, 848)
    self.runbtr = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    self.runbtr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 670, 75, 23))
    self.runbtr.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("runbtr"))
    self.openbtr = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
    self.openbtr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 670, 75, 23))
    self.openbtr.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("openbtr"))
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(Form)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 701, 501))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))

    self.retranslateUi(Form)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

def retranslateUi(self, Form):
    Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
    self.runbtr.setText(_translate("Form", "run", None))
    self.openbtr.setText(_translate("Form", "open", None))
    self.runbtr.clicked.connect(self.runtext)
    self.openbtr.clicked.connect(self.openfile)

def runtext(self):
    exec str(self.textEdit.toPlainText())   


def openfile(self, path=None):
    if not path:
        path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.openbtr, "Open File", '', "Python Files (*.py *.pyc *pyw)")

    if path:
        inFile = QtCore.QFile(path)
        if inFile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly | QtCore.QFile.Text):
            text = inFile.readAll()

            try:
                # Python v3.
                text = str(text, encoding='ascii')
            except TypeError:
                # Python v2.
                text = str(text)

            self.textEdit.setText(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

using the editor

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

shows the path variables from windows

Comment: _I try to expand `os.path`_...what do you mean by that? `os.path` is a _Python_ module.

Comment: yes i know.
im trying to make the editor behave like when you run script strait from windows.
When run from windows some python script it finds the submodules automatic.
when using editor, and have open a python module script file, it cant not find the submodules that the script needs.
so im trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: I think i see what you mean. When running the script from `cmd`, it probably finds its dependent modules because it knows where to search for them (most likely because `PYTHONPATH` is properly set), you probably could configure the interpreter that your editor uses, accordingly.

Comment: yes so are there a way to add the path to editor. I thought i did it with code
    os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), os.path.expandvars('%Path%'))

still i get the error no module named something

Comment: Can you supply the command that works from `cmd`? The full command, the command output, and the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you meant by the first line after the imports is:

```
sys.path.extend(os.path.expandvars("%Path%").split(os.pathsep))
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser("~"))
```

These lines add to the module search path all the folders in `PATH` env var (I'm not sure that this is such a good idea since there are lots of folders there who don't - or shouldn't - contain python modules) + the user's `HOME`.

Comment: im trying to open for test a example file by module pygame.
http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: im trying to open for test a example file by module pygame.
http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
output 
NameError: global name 'pygame' is not defined
so the app cant find the submodules in the example.

Comment: Which is the file? and if you run from cmd `python pygamefile.py` it works?

Comment: Yes works fine via cmd.from the code editor it don't,this is the question I have been asking all along how to make the editor behave like this.remember this is a code editor so subprocess I can't use.I need a way to run to interpreter

Comment: i think the problem is, when i open file into textbox and execute it.Its basiclly a ghost file. i think maybe i gotta save it somehow before exec.